# SerialPort Write() sending more bytes than in send buffer

Tags: c#, serial-port, modbus, crc16

I have a very strange problem, i am **transmitting** an 105 byte[] buffer, and constantly **receiving** 116 bytes on the other side.

The last 2 bytes on the original data is **CRC16**

The code that I am using for transmission is, its looping forever.

```
    static SerialPort sp = null;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         //105 bytes send buffer
        byte[] data = new byte[] {0xa,0x03,0x64,0x0e,0x15,0x00,0x01,0x00,
                                  0x01,0x00,0x06,0x00,0x23,0x00,0x5f,0x00,
                                  0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x7c,0x00,0x00,0x00,
                                  0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
                                  0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,
                                  0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,
                                  0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
                                  0x00,0x00,0x00,0x25,0xb8,0x00,0x05,0xff,
                                  0x23,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xa2,0x00,
                                  0x00,0x02,0x20,0x00,0x04,0x00,0x03,0x00,
                                  0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
                                  0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x1f,0x00,
                                  0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xae,
                                  0x1f
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Serial Port Test");
        sp = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200);
        sp.Open();
        if (sp.IsOpen)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Begining to transmit serial data..");
        }
        for (; ; )
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            sp.Write(data,0,data.Length);
            sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End of transmission");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

What i constantly get on the other side is the following 116 bytes (How strange is it that the message ends with the original **CRC** bytes??)

```
0xa, 0x03, 0x64, 0x0e, 0x15, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,
0x01, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x23, 0x00, 0x5f, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x25, 0xb8, 0x00,
0x05, 0xff, 0xff, 0x23, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0xa2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x20, 0x00, 0x04,
0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
0x00, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0xae, 0x1f,
```

Any help will be appreciated to fix this issue,

Thank you

Comment: So you're getting double-ups on all of the 0xFF bytes.  Do you have the receiver code as well?

Comment: Hi the receiver is an Tibbo RS232 to IP module. I have tested this module with the modbus slave, and it works, its just the .net application that cant "transmit" the original data correctly it seems

Comment: Why are you calling `sp.DiscardOutBuffer()`? If there are any bytes remaining in the serial port's hardware buffer, it will discard them. Which it looks like is happening.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Hi, i just tried that incase, but it does not make a difference, i get the 116 bytes coming out there forever....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue,

It seems "Inband commands" setting was enabled on the Tibbo module, and after disabling it, it stopped "padding" the 0xFF bytes with extra 0xFF bytes.

Very strange, since it does not do this with the original modbus slave which sends lots of 0xFF bytes.